# Adding surfaceview to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, surfaceview, android-tablayout

I have the following custom `SurfaceView class`

`public class Maze extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback`

On my `fragment class` this is how I am currently adding the `Maze` to a `RelativeLayout` container.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
        maze = new Maze(this.getContext());
        ((RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridmapLayout)).addView(maze);
        return rootView;
    }
```

Somehow adding the `SurfaceView` resets the background to black(see comment on xml file).

**fragment_1.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"> // this gets removed.

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridmapLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Another issue I am getting is I am implementing a `viewPager` and `TabLayout` to navigate between `Fragment`. With the `SurfaceView` attached to `fragment1`, when I try to navigate via the tab to `fragment2`, fragment2 UI doesn't load. Navigating via sliding the viewPager works though. Not sure what is going on here.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapater(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }


    private class CustomAdapater extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private String fragments[] = {"Control", "Log", "Connection"};

        public CustomAdapater(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, Context applicationContext) {
            super(supportFragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Fragment1();
                case 1:
                    return new Fragment2();
                case 2:
                    return new Fragment3();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragments[position];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the background is removed and it is not just the surfaceView which is black?!

Comment: Solved both issues by limiting the size using `surfaceView.getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height)`